# How to get twitter handle from tweet using Tweepy API 2.0

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using the Twitter API StreamingClient using the python module Tweepy. I am currently doing a short stream where I am collecting tweets and saving the entire ID and text from the tweet inside of a json object and writing it to a file.

My goal is to be able to collect the Twitter handle from each specific tweet and save it to a json file (preferably print it in the output terminal as well).

This is what the current code looks like:

```py
KEY_FILE = './keys/bearer_token'
DURATION = 10

def on_data(json_data):
    json_obj = json.loads(json_data.decode())
    #print('Received tweet:', json_obj)
    print(f'Tweet Screen Name: {json_obj.user.screen_name}')
    with open('./collected_tweets/tweets.json', 'a') as out:
        json.dump(json_obj, out)

bearer_token = open(KEY_FILE).read().strip()
streaming_client = tweepy.StreamingClient(bearer_token)
streaming_client.on_data = on_data
streaming_client.sample(threaded=True)
time.sleep(DURATION)
streaming_client.disconnect()
```

And I have no idea how to do this, the only thing I found is that someone did this:

```
json_obj.user.screen_name
```

However, this did not work at all, and I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things

Firstly, I'd recommend using `on_response` rather than `on_data` because StreamClient already defines a `on_data` function to parse the json. (Then it will fire `on_tweet`, `on_response`, `on_error`, etc)

Secondly, `json_obj.user.screen_name` is part of API v1 I believe, which is why it doesn't work.

---

To get extra data using Twitter Apiv2, you'll want to use Expansions and Fields ([Tweepy Documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/expansions_and_fields.html), [Twitter Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/expansions))

For your case, you'll probably want to use `"username"` which is under the `user_fields`.

```py
def on_response(response:tweepy.StreamResponse):
    tweet:tweepy.Tweet = response.data
    users:list = response.includes.get("users") 
    # response.includes is a dictionary representing all the fields (user_fields, media_fields, etc)
    # response.includes["users"] is a list of `tweepy.User`
    # the first user in the list is the author (at least from what I've tested)
    # the rest of the users in that list are anyone who is mentioned in the tweet
    
    author_username = users and users[0].username
    print(tweet.text, author_username)

streaming_client = tweepy.StreamingClient(bearer_token)
streaming_client.on_response = on_response
streaming_client.sample(threaded=True, user_fields = ["id", "name", "username"]) # using user fields 

time.sleep(DURATION)
streaming_client.disconnect()
```

Hope this helped.

<sub>*also tweepy documentation definitely needs more examples for api v2*</sub>

Comment: Hey, i tried your approach, and i tried printing just the handles in themselves, but everything just popped up as "None". Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```py
KEY_FILE = './keys/bearer_token'
DURATION = 10

def on_data(json_data):
    json_obj = json.loads(json_data.decode())
    print('Received tweet:', json_obj)
    with open('./collected_tweets/tweets.json', 'a') as out:
        json.dump(json_obj, out)

bearer_token = open(KEY_FILE).read().strip()
streaming_client = tweepy.StreamingClient(bearer_token)
streaming_client.on_data = on_data
streaming_client.on_closed = on_finish
streaming_client.sample(threaded=True, expansions="author_id", user_fields="username", tweet_fields="created_at")
time.sleep(DURATION)
streaming_client.disconnect()
```